Translation: Do you speak English or Japanese?
I'm going to Seoul for the first time and I have a phrase book but 'or' is a little beyond the six words of Korean I now know. If anyone could let me know how to say "do you speak English or Japanese?" simply and politely, this tourist would be most grateful.
Thank you in advance!

In Korea, many people know Japanese, but it's not common to ask strangers if they speak Japanese. It's better to just ask if they speak English.

I agree hanasiu.
you just ask by english.
I don't know what is six words that you know.

'당신은 영어나 일본어를 할 수 있나요'
The above is a direct translation of the sentence you provided, but it sounds awkward in spoken Korean.
'실례합니다. 혹시 영어나 일본어 하세요?' would be nice if you try to talk with a stranger in Korea.
